# Bootstrap 3 responsive layout

Tags: html, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, smartphone

Im trying to align my section content exactly the same in every screen resolution I tried to use min-width and max-width but it isnt working as it should here is the code and the working link is

http://www.cinqomedia-test.com/cs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
<meta name="description" content="Creative Style is one of Bahrain's most highly regarded providers of contemporary interior design services.">
<meta name="author" content="Cinqo Media">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png">
<title>Creative Style - Stylish, Comfortable & Luxurious Furniture</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/onepage-scroll.css" />


<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">            </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body cz-shortcut-listen="true" id="fade">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/creative-style-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Creative Style"></a>
</div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<section class="page1">
<div class="layer">
<div class="container theme-showcase">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Class Defined</h1>
    <h4>Since 2002, Kingdom of Bahrain</h4>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">View More Projects</a>  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="page2">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <div class="section2">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>Donec faucibus ipsum id sapien ultrices, a vulputate elit imperdiet. Morbi at euismod nisi. Praesent venenatis tempus ligula. Nunc dignissim ullamcorper velit, eu semper metus imperdiet vel. Nulla gravida mauris a nunc hendrerit, ut gravida diam hendrerit. Nam ac tempus felis, a posuere justo. Proin sollicitudin elit commodo consequat vulputate. Mauris convallis consectetur nulla vestibulum iaculis. Nulla facilisi. Nunc quis arcu urna.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Read More</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="page3">
<div class="container theme-showcase">
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Donec faucibus ipsum id sapien ultrices, a vulputate elit imperdiet. Morbi at euismod nisi. Praesent venenatis tempus ligula. Nunc dignissim ullamcorper velit, eu semper metus imperdiet vel. Nulla gravida mauris a nunc hendrerit, ut gravida diam hendrerit. Nam ac tempus felis, a posuere justo. Proin sollicitudin elit commodo consequat vulputate. Mauris convallis consectetur nulla vestibulum iaculis. Nulla facilisi. Nunc quis arcu urna.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Read More</a>
</div>
</div>
</section>


</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".main").onepage_scroll({
      sectionContainer: "section"
    });
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.2.0/holder.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues. 1) you have had an extra closing div after the closing div for `<div class="main">`. 2) you have used `col-md-8` div without row or container, so it will consider the width of the parent.

Bootstrap `.container` class has a predefined width according to the screen size. as well as 'col-xx-xx` classes have their own width.

I have modified your markup and added a container and row inside the section. You may have look into this at: http://jsbin.com/OzAMeZI/1 and edit it at http://jsbin.com/OzAMeZI/1/edit .

If you want to get a white arrow shape to the `col-md-8` class, you can consider `:before` or `:after` pseudo` classes to section or container elements. But, please make sure that you use media queried css styles.